# Python giving a 2D list headers

Tags: python, arrays, list, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am trying to give a 2D list headers. Code I have :

```
headers = ['a','b','c','d','e']
list = [['1','2','3','4','5'],['6','7','8','9','10'],
        ['11','12','13','14','15']]
```

I want the output to be:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
a 6
b 7
c 8
d 9
e 10
a 11
b 12
c 13
d 14
e 15
```

Comment: Read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ ... start with loops, try to code it. If you get to a specific problem come back and show your code as [mcve]. SO does not "tutor" languages - you have to learn on your own,

Comment: just a tip .. certain words are already used - `list` is one of them - dont use built-in names - you see some of them here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
headers = ['a','b','c','d','e']
list = [['1','2','3','4','5'],['6','7','8','9','10'],
        ['11','12','13','14','15']] 

for i in range(len(list)) :
    for j in range(len(list[i])):
        print(headers[j],list[i][j])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function # py2 compatibility
>>> headers = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> rows = [['1','2','3','4','5'],['6','7','8','9','10'],['11','12','13','14','15']]
>>> for row in rows:
...   for header, col in zip(headers, row):
...     print(header, col)
... 
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
a 6
b 7
c 8
d 9
e 10
a 11
b 12
c 13
d 14
e 15
```